# How do I put my routes in one module and my handlers in another module

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a Yesod application in which the entire web portion of the application was defined in one file, and it has grown to the size that I need to separate things out.

I want to set up a hirearchy like this:

```
web/Handlers/Group1
             Group2
web/Foundation
web/Main
```

This is similar to how the code for the Haskellers website is set up.  However, I can't figure out how the Haskellers website actually works.  When I set things up, my handlers in Group1 need to import Foundation to get the Foundation class and to get a list of other routes, because some of my handlers redirect to different parts of the app.  But my `Foundation` won't compile because it wants to find the route handlers that are defined in `Group1`, `Group2`, etc.

This is forcing me into a circular import, which obviously won't work.  When I read the Haskellers code, the `Foundation` module does not import any of the `Handler` modules.

What is the trick to make this work?

---

Update

Following Michael Snoyman's answer, I've replaced my call to `mkYesod` with separate calls to `myYesodData` and `mkYesodDispatch`.  GHC complains, of course, if I do both in one file, so I separated stuff out in the first stage of a refactoring:

- All of my code from `Main.hs`, which was all of the code of the web portion of the application, I moved to `WebApp.hs`
- I moved the `main` function from `WebApp.hs` back into `Main.hs`
- In `WebApp.hs` I call `mkYesodData`
- In `Main.hs` I call `mkYesodDispatch`

And the *linker* fails now.  When compiling `Main`, the first module it finds in the import list that it is in this project and not in a library fails to link like so:

```
web/Main.hs:1:1:
    cannot find normal object file `dist/build/invoicedb/invoicedb-tmp/WebApp.o'
    while linking an interpreted expression
```

If I drop `mkYesodDispatch` and `mkYesodData` and return to `mkYesod`, even using this same file structure, the build proceeds perfectly.

So, to review, here are my files:

web/Main.hs:

- The `main` function
- The call to `mkYesodDispatch`

config/routes:

- plain text routing, just like in the scaffold app

web/WebApp.hs:

- My `App` structure
- `mkYesodData`
- instance Yesod App
- instance YesodAuth App
- instance RenderMessage App FormMessage
- All of my routing handlers

---

I have created a trivial example that illustrates this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/savannidgerinel/yesod-decomposition/src/

```
[2 of 3] Compiling Dispatch         ( src/Dispatch.hs, dist/build/yesod-decomposition/yesod-decomposition-tmp/Dispatch.p_o )
src/Dispatch.hs:1:1:
    cannot find normal object file `dist/build/yesod-decomposition/yesod-decomposition-tmp/Foundation.o'
    while linking an interpreted expression
```

If you edit the code, commenting out `mkYesodDispatch` in Dispatch.hs, and replacing `mkYesodData` with `mkYesod` in Foundation.hs, the code will compile successfully.

Note, I'm using `yesod-1.2.4` for this.  If 1.2.6 solves it, then I will get my team upgraded.

Comment: Are you using scaffolding ?

Comment: Not for this project.

Comment: I think Scaffolding will help you. You can put all the routes in `config/route` file. All you handler under `Handler` folder. Yesod has command for automatically adding handlers.

Comment: I have over a thousand lines of code already and cannot afford the time to transition to a completely new architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your code is using a call to `mkYesod`. In order to make a split into multiple modules, you'll instead need to use `mkYesodData` and `mkYesodDispatch` as is done in the scaffolding site. For more information on this, please see the [scaffolding chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template#_foundation_and_application_modules). It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt this technique to work with an existing codebase.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in your `.cabal` file. Make sure that you tell cabal that you are using Template Haskell:

```
executable yesod-decomposition
   ..
   other-extensions: TemplateHaskell
```

So that it knows to build the right object files in the right order.